# sshd: Won't let me cd into remote folder when connecting programmatically

Tags: node.js, ssh, parallels, sshd

I am trying to use a Parallels VM as a build server. I have set up `sshd` on it and configured it to allow me to connect using secure keys. I can connect successfully using the `node-ssh` package. Parallels has nicely mounted my local `Desktop` folder on my Mac, so in my script, I am attempting to access it like this:

```
await ssh.execCommand('cd /home/parallels/Desktop');
```

However, for no given reason, the current working directory never changes.

```
let result = await ssh.execCommand('pwd');
console.log(result.stdout); // outputs: /home/parallels
```

I have also checked `result.code` and `result.stderr` and there is nothing to indicate anything has gone wrong -- the programmatic API flat out does not allow me to navigate to this folder. However, I can access it just fine using the VM or regular `ssh` on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Executed commands on an ssh server (in general) are separate invocations of the user's shell, which means current working directories (among other things) are not persisted.

Your best bet will be to prepend any commands with your `cd <path> &&` to change to the correct directory first. The only other option would be to use an interactive shell session instead, but that is much more difficult to use programmatically as it was designed to be used by a human.